# Plotting y~1/x with stat_smooth

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, smoothing

Good evening,

I am currently trying to plot a reciprocal model of the form y~1/x in a graph. I want to plot the original data, the predicted Y-values and the fitted model (including confidence intervals). Everything is working fine, despite plotting the fitted model with the reciprocal 1/x. I can get log transformations etc. done, but the reciprocal transformation will not work for me. I tried

```
stat_smooth(method="lm", formula= y ~ 1/x)
stat_smooth(method="lm", formula= y ~ poly(x,-1) 
stat_smooth(method="lm", formula= y ~ (x^-1)
```

Does not work.. Is there anything I am missing? I included an example below. Any help is appreciated!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(car)
df <- Leinhardt

df1 <- na.omit(df)
df1 <- df1[order(infant),]

df1["reincome"] <- 1/(df1$income)

model3 <- lm(infant~reincome, df1)

df1["yhat"]<- predict(model3)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=income, y=infant))+
  geom_point()+geom_point(aes(y=df1$yhat), color="red")+
  stat_smooth(method="lm",formula=  y ~ 1/x)
```

Comment: Did you try `formula=  y ~ I(1/x)`?

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much! It works, but I don't know why. In  '?stat_smooth' I couldn't find anything about the I()? Do you have a quick link to read more about it? Thanks!

Comment: It's a R formula thing - you'll find information on it e.g. here: https://www.google.com/search?q=r+formula+asis . Operators like `+` have special meanings in formulars. `I` makes R interpret it 'as is' .

Comment: Hm, now I am trying to do the same thing with a log-log model. I tried `formula= log(y) ~ log(x)`. This won't work, however. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm why? It does what it should for me ...

Comment: I only get a straight, horizontal line. Should look quite similar to my reciprocal model.

Comment: If you write `y=log(infant)` instead of `y=infant`, it looks not horizontal any more.

Comment: It's not what I expected. But maybe I just lack the understanding... As this is not a discussion board, I want to end this one and thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `I` to indicate that `1/x` should be treated ‘as is’ (`?AsIs` for help):

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=income, y=infant))+
  geom_point()+geom_point(aes(y=df1$yhat), color="red")+
  stat_smooth(method="lm",formula=  y ~ I(1/x))
```